# Storing values of dynamically generated inputs in state

Tags: reactjs

**Scenario:**
You have an input field on a page, and whatever **number** user puts in, I want to generate that much more inputs. Each input generated represents values that user can choose. By default, we generate values from 0 -> N.

*Example*: 
if user sets input to **5** we would generate 5 inputs, each having values from 0 -> 4

**Problem:**
The values we generate by default might change. For example, user maybe wants to change one of the inputs to his value.

*Example*: 
Users sets 5, we generate 5 inputs, from 0 -> 4, then he decides that we wants to change one of the values to 42. In that case, we would have, for example:

input1: 0
input2: 1
input3: 3
input4: 42

**Question**
I want/need to have this values in state because otherwise I can not update the value as they type into the inputs.

The problem I am facing is: **how can I know which one he is typing into**?   The inputs are generated dynamically.

If I set inputs to have a **inputChangeHandler()** what to check inside that function to know which state value to change? 
Also, since other values need to be preserved, I only need to change that key, not others.. Lots of issues I am facing as you see. :) 
Any advice would be appreciated.

**Demo**
Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gaq7eh
Live: https://react-gaq7eh.stackblitz.io (input is in the top left corner)

P.S - not sure if editor changes reflect everywhere, so just in case, here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class InputProblem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputs: [],
      inputValue: null
    };
  }

  generateInputs = (value) => {
    this.setState({inputs: Array.from(Array(Number(value)).keys()), inputValue: Number(value)})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <input className="main-input" type="text" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={(e) => this.generateInputs(e.target.value)} />
      {
        this.state.inputs.map(item => (
          <input type="text" value={item}/>
        ))
      }
      </div>

    )
  }
}
render(<InputProblem />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option without changing too much code is figuring out which input it is by keeping track of index in an `onChange` handler for each respective `input`

```
handleInputTextUpdate = (idx) = (e) => {
  const nextInputState = [...this.state.inputs]
  nextInputState[idx] = e.target.value
  this.setState({inputs: nextInputState})
}
this.state.inputs.map((item, index) => (
  <input onChange={this.handleInputTextUpdate(index)} />
)
```

Comment: Both answers provided some insight, but I managed to get it working using your suggestion. I actually thought about doing this but decided it was a "dirty" solution (copying state to another object then setting it back). Unfortunately, I found no other elegant solutions. Thank you for your help, Andrew!

Comment: There are more elegant methods of handling this, but I prefaced it with low code changes ;). If you want a better solution, make `this.state.inputs` an object, where the key is a unique id. It's essentially the same process, only you would be more declarative with a distinct id, instead of an index number

Answer (score 1):

You can add an unique id to each `input`, and then you can use this `id` to figure out which `input` is changing.

```
 this.state.inputs.map((item, index) => (
        <input type="text" key={index} id={index} value={item} 
        onChange={(e) => {  console.log("e.target.id: "+ e.target.id + " value: " + e.target.value)}} />
        ))
```

Access element's `id` with `e.target.id`.

Comment: if I set value={item} then it can not be changed. I have to set it to something like {this.state.my_custom_key} which I haven't set yet. Any suggestion on how/where to do that?

Comment: @py9 I would use an array. Like this: yourArray[e.target.id] = e.target.value

Comment: I decided to go with Andrew's solution as I managed to get it working with that technique first :) Nevertheless, thank you for your time and solution. Definitely pushed me into right direction.